# LSTM model predicting some column correct while rest giving random number

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am working on a AI model trying to predict inahalable particle number among 7 people.
I have 7 columns indicating 7 occupants inhalable particle number over 30 mins. I have multiple cases with different parameter varied. there is only one infector in each case, and occupants take turn to be an infector.

The problem is that the model predicts the infector's inhalable particl number pretty well while it cannot preict rest or susceptible's inhalable particle numbers. It even gives negative numbers while none of my data are

I am not sure what is wrong with it. its so weird that the model can predict the infector's particle number so well, but not the susceptible's.

I think its because the number meausred for infector is too high compared to the number measured for susceptible. well its obvious since infector emits particle. But I am not sure

I have tried to change loss function to MSE, MAE, and trying to create a custom loss function.

I am trying to separate the infector column and susceptible column and create two different model, but I could not reach to that point.

Do you guys think that creating separate infector and susceptible model would solve the problem?

What should I do?

Comment: The question is quite broad and it's difficult to understand the problem you're solving or the issues, given the description but the part about the model outputting negative values looks addressable. If you want to enforce non-negative outputs, you must design a model that is constrained to predicting only non-negative values., for example with an appropriate [activation function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/436636/69501).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear enough but I'll provide some potential solutions to deal with such discrepancies.

1. Data Imbalance: Try balancing the dataset by using augmentation. Or implement `oversampling`/`undersampling` to equalize the number of samples for each category.
2. Normalization: Normalize input data before passing it into the model as it helps the model to converge during training.
3. Loss Function: Consider making a custom loss function that takes into account the specific characteristics of your problem.

Comment: there is no number of sample discrepancy. I have multiple cases and each case has one infector. I meant the particle number for infector is very huge compared to the susceptible and the model can predict the particle number for infector only.
do you think that separating the infector data from susceptible data would resolve the problem?

Comment: and I also tried minmax scaler and standard scaler, but both did not solve the problem

Comment: One way to address this issue is by designing a custom loss function that takes into account the difference in particle numbers and penalizes the model more for incorrect predictions of susceptible data.